# Adding outlets dynamically in MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to generate buttons and outlets dynamically from e.g. data. I am used to developing web-applications where I can generate the links from the data, but I can't see how this can be done in MonoTouch?

I basically want to create a UINavigationController and fill the layout from data I receive from a database or a-like, and then link the button to a page displaying some information about the topic. Can this be done in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to look at the [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) library (scroll down for documentation and screenshots). It comes with a sample application that shows you how you can, very easily, create UI based on code, reflection...

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly what I was looking for. Just didn't think of Dialog as the area to look for.